# How to edit Elastic Beanstalk code without re-uploading application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am building a web-app using Elastic beanstalk on AWS and was wondering if there was a way that I can edit the source code without having to re-upload a zip of my application every time I want to make an edit.

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to edit code on the server and then choose "Restart App Server(s)" in the Elastic Beanstalk web console. That being said, you'd be better off developing and testing code in your local environment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Elastic Beanstalk environment is based on EC2 instances. You can connect to your instances using SSH and, inside the instance, download your source code. If you use a non compiled language, like Javascript (Node) or Python you can edit the code directly. If you use Java you will need to upload the source code and compile it. Maybe using the environment JDK.

But keep in mind two details:

1. You must install your compiled/edited code in the same path used by elastic beanstalk;
2. If your instance is reinitialized, your changes will be lost, because in this case eb will get a fresh copy of your code based on your last upload.